# random variable converging almost surely to zero times a random variable with bounded moments

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, strong-convergence

Say that $\{X_n\}$ are none-negative random variables converging almost surely to zero, and $Y_n$ are a sequence of i.i.d random variable, non-negative, with finite $r$-moment for any $r>0$, and whose distribution does not depend on $n$.
Then $X_nY_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability (using Markov inequality), but is it true that  $X_nY_n\rightarrow 0$ almost surely?

If $Y_n\rightarrow Y$ almost surely then it was true due to the continuous mapping. But is it true when $Y_n$ has no limit (but has finite moments that do not depend on $n$)?

**Edit: answer given in the comments**

Julius's comment answers my question. If the moments are not bounded (that is, there is a constant $C$ such that $EY_n^r<C$ for all $r>0$, then we can't deduce almost sure convergence.

Comment: Is there $C$ surch that for all $r$, the $r$th moment is bounded by $C$ ? Or is it for all $r$ there is $C$ [...] ?

Comment: If you only need the $r$-moments to exist for any $r > 0$, then take $X_n = 1/(\log(n))$ and $Y_n \sim \text{Exp}(1)$ random variables. Then $\mathbb{P}(X_n Y_n \geq 1) = 1/n$, and so $X_n Y_n \geq 1$ infinitely often almost surely, by the second Borel-Cantelli lemma. So $X_n \rightarrow 0$ almost-surely (in fact, determinitistically), and $Y_n$ is an i.i.d. sequence of random variables with finite moments of all orders, but $X_n Y_n$ does not converge to $0$ almost-surely..